# Can you map in require.js in a vendor/module to overwrite an HTML file in another vendor/module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, vendor, map

Instead of overwriting an HTML file in a core or 3rd party vendor/module via app/code, could you do it from another vendor/module via mapping in require.js?

Answer (score 0):

You never write code in vendor. Why ? Because each time composer will run in the deployment env, it will erase all your modifications.

This is not just magento related, it's for all projects running composer.

So, no, you have to override in `app/code` and/or `app/design`

Comment: I havn't explained my question well enough. A brand new custom vendor/module is created, and that would be used to modify behavior in the 3rd party and/or core module.